# Why does solute potential go up as temperatures go down?

Tags: temperature, osmosis

So the closer a solution's solute potential is to zero, the more water potential said solution would eventually have. The solute potential equation is -iCRT. If the temperature is 0, -iCRT would be equal to zero, and because temperature is measured in Kelvin, this would mean the solution is at absolute zero. Things can't move at absolute zero. How is it that that water has the most potential to move at absolute zero?

Same with the opposite.

If the temperature is high, wouldn't that mean water potential would be at its highest because water molecules are at high energy, jumping around everywhere?

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stackexchange. It sounds to me like your question isn't actually about biology, so I've voted that it should be moved to Chemistry Stackexchange instead. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this is where I got my water potential information: https://goo.gl/t6LgvX

Comment: @user1136 — Water potential may be of concern to workers in many areas of science, just as may pH and ionization, chemical bonding, electricity etc. That does not make any of these appropriate for a SE site dedicated to questions in biology when there are SE sites specifically dedicated to chemistry and physics. It also makes sense to ask chemistry questions on SE Chemistry because they are more likely to get authoratitive answers (which will show up when a scientist from any discipline makes an internet search) there.